# California: Bob is going on a trip. Mechanic is fixing his car. Bob reached out to get it back, but M is unresponsive. Can M charge for storage?

Tags: california, liability, driving, car-title

This is a follow-up to [California: A mechanic serviced Bob's car, has it in his shop, and verbally agreed to buy it from him. Is Bob liable for accidents before it's sold?](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/74767/california-a-mechanic-serviced-my-car-has-it-in-his-shop-and-verbally-agreed) and it contains a lot more context, but here is the tl;dr version:

> Bob took his car in to a mechanic (“M”). After M worked on it, Bob decided to
> sell it to M. It's currently in M’s shop but it'll take Bob over two
> weeks to sign over the title.

Due to the holidays, Bob won't be in town for a few days and M is very busy. Bob's been doing his best to keep everything in writing (text messages and emails) but M's not responding to any of them. M picks up the phone when Bob calls, though.

Bob asked him at least four times (on separate days) for an itemized list of the work M already put into the car and Bob has not received it.

If M doesn't get back to Bob before Bob's trip, can M charge him for storage? Bob texted and emailed him this:

> If M decides to hold onto the car, Bob will not be responsible for storage fees, but Bob is more than happy to pick up the car today.

Obviously I don't know if that holds water otherwise I wouldn't be asking this question. Can he charge Bob for storage even though Bob's been proactive about taking it off his hands before his trip?

Comment: I recommend that you only ask hypotheticals and not personal legal advice. People typically refer to the parties of their questions as Bob, Alice etc.

Comment: @kisspuska Thank you.I will edit this

Comment: sure, made a few edits too.

Comment: @kisspuska *I* do. But without thinking, Bob agreed to the deal over the phone. Now Bob kind of feels like it would be dishonorable to change his mind unless a scam could be proven.

Comment: Maybe these questions/answers respectively are informational to the instant hypo: 1. https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/47256/can-phone-conversations-be-used-in-court-as-defense/65260#65260 2. https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/74295/where-can-a-sample-of-a-recorder-warning-tone-compliant-with-federal-standard-10/74296#74296 3. https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/74552/recording-only-your-own-voice-during-a-telephone-call/74556#74556

Comment: @kisspuska "hypo" = hypothesis?

Comment: Hypothetical fact pattern, or hypothetical case